# CakePHP SQL Operation using 'OR'

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePHP `find` to retrieve the data. I need to use `OR` between conditions so i used following query as stated in CakePHP documentation. This works perfectly other times but the problem arises when the field name is same in `OR array`, `Group.arrival_date` in this case.

```
$this->Group->find('all', 
               array('conditions' => array(
                       'OR' => array( 
                          'Group.arrival_date' => 'DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)',
                          'Group.arrival_date' => 'DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)'
                       )
                   )
                ));
```

The SQL it generate is

```
SELECT `Group`.`id`, `Group`.`rr_no`, `Group`.`package_id`, `Group`.`user_id`, 
`Group`.`group_name`, `Group`.`pax`, `Group`.`agent_id`, `Group`.`staff_id`, 
`Group`.`arrival_date`, `Group`.`departure_date`, `Group`.`status`, `Group`.`slug`, 
`Group`.`book_flight`, `Group`.`allocated_tents`, `Group`.`alert`, `Group`.`alert_seen` 
FROM `groups` AS `Group` WHERE `Group`.`arrival_date` = 'DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)'
```

It takes the second condition only. For different field name like:

```
$this->Group->find('all', 
                array('conditions' => array(                                                                    
                          'OR' => array( 
                            'Group.slug' => 'slug1',
                            'Group.group_name' => 'group1'
                          )
                      )
              ));
```

The generated SQL is

```
SELECT `Group`.`id`, `Group`.`rr_no`, `Group`.`package_id`, `Group`.`user_id`, 
`Group`.`group_name`, `Group`.`pax`, `Group`.`agent_id`, `Group`.`staff_id`, 
`Group`.`arrival_date`, `Group`.`departure_date`, `Group`.`status`, `Group`.`slug`, 
`Group`.`book_flight`, `Group`.`allocated_tents`, `Group`.`alert`, `Group`.`alert_seen` 
FROM `groups` AS `Group` WHERE ((`Group`.`slug` = 'slug1') OR (`Group`.`group_name` = 'group1'))
```

Which is as expected. What am i missing in the first find i used? How can i get the above query work? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using CakePHP 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->Group->find('all', 
               array('conditions' => array(
                       'OR' => array( 
                          array('Group.arrival_date' => 'DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)'),
                          array('Group.arrival_date' => 'DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)')
                       )
                   )
                ));
```

Or you could use `IN`:

```
$this->Group->find('all', 
                 array('conditions' => array(
                     'Group.arrival_date' => array('DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)', 'DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)')
                  )
              );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! First one worked but not the second one. The second one generates valid SQL using `in` but they return different data.

Answer (score 0):

For same field, simply put all values you need for OR in an array.

```
$this->Group->find('all', 
               array('conditions' => array(

                          'Group.arrival_date' => 
          array('DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)', 'DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)' )
                   )
                ));
```